# preg_match with php Compilation failed

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I try to match this expression :

> * ^X-Spam-Flag: YES

I use this code :

```
if(preg_match('\'* ^X-Spam-Flag: YES\'', $value))
```

But i have this error :

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at
>   offset 0

Problem with regex and * and ^ but can i correct that ?

Comment: You need delimiters. Try: `if(preg_match("/\* \^X-Spam-Flag: YES/i", $value))`

Comment: Works fine for me.. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/r8y-p52

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing your delimiters.

Change to:

```
preg_match('#\'* ^X-Spam-Flag: YES\'#', $value)
```

Or maybe you need:

```
preg_match('#\* \^X-Spam-Flag: YES#', $value)
```

Comment: Need to escape the caret `^`

Comment: also escape the asterisk `*`

Answer (score 1):

You was near the solution, you have to escape `^` and `*` since these have a special meaning in a regex pattern:

```
if(preg_match('\'\* \^X-Spam-Flag: YES\'', $value))
```

If your escaped single quotes look strange and may be better replaced by `/` or `~` ... however these can be used as delimiters.

More informations about delimiters here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 0):

To safely escape Regex special characters, you can simply use "preg_quote()", which adds backslashes in front of these characters.

```
if(preg_match('\'* ^X-Spam-Flag: YES\'', preg_quote($value)))
```